# How to split a certain area using python?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

My screen has different areas: one *3D View* and two *Image Editors*.

I would like to split one of the Image Editors but when I call the `bpy.ops.screen.area_split()` operator, it's always going to split the *3D View* for whatever reason.

Does anyone know how I can split a certain area?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/splitting-of-screen-areas-and-retrieving-the-active-area-with-python   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56911/how-to-open-a-new-editor-with-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate through [all visible areas](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.type) and [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) when calling [`area_split()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html?highlight=area_split#bpy.ops.screen.area_split) operator.

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR': # 'VIEW_3D', 'CONSOLE', 'INFO' etc. 
        with context.temp_override(area=area):
            bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction='VERTICAL', factor=0.3)
        break
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR': # 'VIEW_3D', 'CONSOLE', 'INFO' etc. 
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.screen.area_split(override, direction='VERTICAL', factor=0.3)
        break
```

Comment: Was off searchin' for a particular answer on this, didn't see yours.  Closed and Re-opened.